# VBA WORD: Match paragraph followed by picture?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Apologies to the people who keep reading my questions which are similar to each other. I'm just starting so eventually something will click.

OK I want to get rid of any gaps (that aren't words/letters) between shapes. I.e. if I have two small shapes on consecutive lines I want to remove the line break.

I tried this:

```
Sub RemovePicGaps()
    wrdDoc.Content.Select

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^13([!A-Za-z]@)^13"
        .Replacement.Text = "\1^p"

        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With

GoHere:
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    If Selection.Find.Execute = True Then
        GoTo GoHere
    End If

End Sub
```

But its not matching what I want and also I'd rather there be something specific to pictures if possible (rather than just 'not letters').

EDIT: HERS WHAT I WANT TO HAPPEN:
THIS:
[image]

TO:
[image]

For those interested, those are pictures of the anatomy of the mouth. Very excitingly boring.

Comment: Hi again :) can you add a print screen to present current situation and sample 'gaps' which you want to get rid off?? Just to better understand your needs...

Comment: and see you use my logic from [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035530/vba-word-remove-double-paragraph-marks) of yours... :) happy to see it!