# Select text w/o the paragraph mark

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a problem when assigning text in a Word document (usually one line) to a variable. The problem is that the paragraph mark also gets assigned to the variable and that causes the external system to reject the variable.

Since it's just one line, I do:

```
Selection.WholeStory
var = Selection.Text
```

In the external system, when assigning this var to a text box, the paragraph mark gets inserted and then processed as `#`.

How can I assign the text below to a variable w/o the paragraph mark:

```
This is a sample text with paragraph mark^p
```

Comment: this should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035530/vba-word-remove-double-paragraph-marks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove the `vbCr`:

```
Selection.WholeStory
var = Selection.Text
var = Replace(var, vbCr, "")
```